# Update Rails app to Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Rails 3 application and I want to update it to Rails 4.

Currently, this is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.11'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'devise'
gem 'pygments.rb'
gem 'redcarpet'
gem "jquery-rails"
gem 'will_paginate'
gem 'binding_of_caller'
gem 'lazybox'
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
  gem "compass-rails"
end

group :development do
  gem "app_reset"
  gem "letter_opener"
end
```

Will upgrading it Rails 4 some things? The app is a simple blog application that allows users to create posts and has user authentication.

The reason why I'd like to update it is to use Turbolinks and any other cool new features that may benefit me.

Is it as simple as changing the gem rails to `gem 'rails', '4.0.0'`?

If I've missed any important info out, let me know and I'll edit this question.

Comment: Rails 4 hasn't been released yet. It is still in beta. So, `gem 'rails', '4.0.0'` isn't going to work. Even if it did, there will be more to it than simply changing the gem. Have you done any research about upgrading to Rails 4?

Comment: anyway, you should upgrade to 3.2.13...

Answer (score 2):

The documentation is not final and still a work in progress but I'd recommend you check out firstly:

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_0_release_notes.html

Which give you a overview of changes from 3.2 to 4.0 and then read:

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#upgrading-from-rails-3-2-to-rails-4-0

Which provides you with instructions for upgrading, it is a bit more complex than just changing the version in the gemfile.

You should also check to make sure the gems you are using don't have any issues with Rails 4.0.

Comment: I think I'm going to keep my app at Rails 3 since it's almost near production and all I want is turbo links so I can just install the gem for that. Is there a list of Rails versions that have security issues? I heard a while ago that a few had some problems and wanted to know if my version is ok to use.

Comment: The version you are currently using has known security issues. I'd recommend you upgrade to the latest 3.2.x version which at this time is 3.2.13

Comment: @user2203362, I recommend following [@rails](https://twitter.com/rails) on Twitter. Any security issues and/or new releases will be reported there. It's always a good idea to be on the latest stable release.

Comment: @Tomdarkness How do I update it to that then? Do I replace the first gem with `gem 'rails', '3.2.13'` and `sudo gem update`?

Comment: @user2203362, change your Gemfile to `gem 'rails', '3.2.13'` and then do `bundle update`.

Answer (score 0):

from the rails blog:

> If you're upgrading an existing application to Rails 4, have a look at
>   the upgrade guide or the Railscast screencast. As always, install the
>   latest with `gem install rails --version 4.0.0 --no-ri --no-rdoc` or
>   depend on the `v4.0.0` tag. If you haven't already, now is a good time
>   to upgrade to Ruby 2.0 as well. Rails 5+ will require Ruby 2.0, so you
>   might as well get a head start.

Resources mentioned: [railscast #415 - upgrading to rails 4.0](http://railscasts.com/episodes/415-upgrading-to-rails-4)

Official upgrade guide: [upgrading to rails 4.0 guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#upgrading-from-rails-3-2-to-rails-4-0)